# I have problem with google maps and a placepicker

Tags: android

I've linked my app with Google Services API and every thing else accordingly but when I run the app it crashes inside the "try catch":

```
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder=new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

    try {
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), 1);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {

        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(e.getConnectionStatusCode(),PromotionActivity.this,0);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Google play service not Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

> UncaughtException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   zzcd(Landroid/content/Context;)V in class
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability; or its super
>   classes (declaration of
>   'com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability' appears in
>   /data/app/com.example.hotspot_v3-c585BnIHksVY_Mk2yo2H3g==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk

Comment: you need to update all google dependencies

Comment: It worked thanks a lot @HiteshKushwah